# UIStackview not resizing when hiding the labels inside it

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uistackview

Hi I'm new to UIStackViews.
So I have a vertical Stackview containing 8 Labels.
However, the problem with my Stackview is that whenever I hide the Labels inside it, my stackview does not resize.

[The labels within the Red Rectangle are in my Stackview](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/422660792173985813/470431116029984779/Screen_Shot_2018-07-22_at_1.19.22_pm.png?width=267&height=471)
[When I hide those labels of the Stackview, I want my screen to look like this](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/422660792173985813/470431168043679764/Screen_Shot_2018-07-22_at_1.19.09_pm_copy.png?width=274&height=471)
[However for some reason when I hide those labels, it looks like this instead with all the space visible and the stuff at the bottom doesn't go up](https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/422660792173985813/470431265980416060/Screen_Shot_2018-07-22_at_1.19.09_pm.png?width=274&height=471)

How do I fix this?
Here's how I hid the labels:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        showingResultLabel.isHidden = true
        addressLabel.isHidden = true
        costOfKitLabel.isHidden = true
        costOfModularLabel.isHidden = true
        dispatchedFromLabel.isHidden = true
        kitHomecostLabel.isHidden = true
        modularHomecostLabel.isHidden = true
        dispatchFromLabel.isHidden = true
```

Thanks

Comment: it looks like you have to hide red area and move orange area up. and red area in stackview but the orange area is not in stack view . right??

Comment: @HiteshAgarwal  That is right!

Comment: check constraint if you set fix height to stackview ??

Comment: Hi my stackview has no constraints

Comment: may be you set constraint to bottom label which don't let it go up. have you set bottom constaint equal to for "estimate de..." label

Comment: @HiteshAgarwal None of my labels, buttons have constraints and i still have this problem

Comment: you should add constraints. Because when you hide lebels in stackview stackview size changes but due to no constraint it won't move up.

Comment: where should i add constraints

Comment: Hitesh is right - you need constraints for your stackView, otherwise it doesn't know what size should it have.

Answer (score 1):

Just hide the labels works. You need to set constraints to make it work. I upload images of constraints.

[image]

stackview's constraint

[image]

Answer (score 0):

hiding a label inside stack view does not effect the height. 
I suggest that, when you want to show some detail (stackView contain some UILabel),

create the UILabel e.g:

```
 let label = UILabel()
   label.textColor = .black
   label.text = ""
   label.backgroundColor = .clear
```

then add the UILabelView to the stack view

```
stackViewName.addArrangedSubview(label)
```

at the end, instead of hide a label inside stack view, you have to remove the UILabel from the stack view

```
stackView.removeArrangedSubview(label)
```

so i think this will effect the hight of your stackView .

Comment: " first add the parameter to the UILabel then add the UILabelView to the stack view"  sorry what does this mean

Comment: Alright I tried that but it still did not push the stuff at the bottom to the top

Comment: ok then, you can set the stackView height statically after removing the object           stackView.frame.size.height = 0